# Change Layer name when converting from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I am converting GeoJSON files to other formats (including KML) using `ogr2ogr`.

As you may know, there is no field in a GeoJSON file to specify the name of the layer, causing every conversion to have the name `OGRGeoJSON`. For example the following GeoJSON file:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
      "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
      }
     ]
   }
```

is converted as follows in KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document><Folder><name>OGRGeoJSON</name>
<Schema name="OGRGeoJSON" id="OGRGeoJSON">
    <SimpleField name="Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Description" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="prop0" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#OGRGeoJSON">
        <SimpleData name="prop0">value0</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>102.0,0.5</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder></Document></kml>
```

I've read this [blog post](http://mateusz.loskot.net/2007/11/06/ogr-geojson-driver/) from 2007 explaining why this occurs and I know that GeoJSON does not have the concept of layer name in its specifications.

I would like to know if there is a simple way to rename the layer on the fly using OGR, or if I should generate the output with `ogr2ogr` and programmatically change the output layer name, depending on the output file format with another program since, as far as I know, the OGR API does not have a function to rename the layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) documentation it outlines the `-nln` property, which allows for specifying an alternate layer name. I don't know how new this is so you may need to download a new version, but it does work.

```
ogr2ogr -f KML some_output.kml example.geojson -nln SOMENAME
```

Using the above command on your example geojson produced the following results:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document><Folder><name>SOMENAME</name>
<Schema name="SOMENAME" id="SOMENAME">
    <SimpleField name="Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Description" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="prop0" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#SOMENAME">
        <SimpleData name="prop0">value0</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>102.0,0.5</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder></Document></kml>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly, at least on the command line. I'm actually calling OGR from Python. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JulienBourdon Glad to hear it. In case you didn't know about it you can use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) to call command line utilities in Pythoon, or the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module for more complex data interaction.