# How do I rename a layer using ogr2ogr?

Tags: layers, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to rename a layer while converting it from a shapefile to sqlite. From looking at the ogr2ogr documents, `-nln name` should do the trick. I've seen [this similar post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111989/how-to-rename-ogr2ogr-tables-on-export-to-spatialite) and [this very similar post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33766/change-layer-name-when-converting-from-geojson)  but neither will work for me.

```
ogr2ogr -f "sqlite" output.sqlite input.shp -nln "new_layer_name"
```

Comment: That's the way to do it. Do you mean that "ogrinfo output.sqlite" does not list "new_layer_name"?

Comment: Yes, the layer name does not change

Comment: Can you post the output of `ogrinfo -so -al output.sqlite` ?

Comment: ... and maybe the same on the input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce with GDAL 2.3.0dev.

Create a SQLite database with -nln parameter

> ogr2ogr -f "sqlite" output.sqlite states.shp -nln "new_layer_name"

Check the result with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo output.sqlite
INFO: Open of output.sqlite using driver `SQLite' successful.
1: new_layer_name (Polygon)
```

The layer appears in the database as it was named with the -nln parameter.

Comment: I checked the file using QGIS and read it's layer name from there which was showing it hadn't changed. When when i used ogrinfo the change was visible